# Virtual monitor using AMD gpu

Tags: xorg, monitor, xrandr

I am trying to setup a virtual monitor with xrandr. I don't have intel gpu, so creating a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` file is not a solution for me... How can I create a virtual display output without having an intel gpu?